# Where the files created by "w" mode in python is saved?

Tags: python

I am New to Python...

I have run a python script in windows. This Is The script

`

```
numbers = range(0, 10)

filename = "output_numbers.txt"

#w tells python we are opening the file to write into it
outfile = open(filename, 'w')

for number in numbers:
    outfile.write(str(number))

outfile.close()
```

`

In which directory are these python created files are saved?
Also, say any errors or mistake you found in this code?

Comment: It will be saved in the directory that this script is running. To save in a specified location, change the file name to a path with file name - `C:/insert/path/here/output.txt`

Comment: They are saved *where you tell them to be saved*. The first argument to `open` is the **path to the file you are creating**. In this case, `output_numbers.txt`. This will be interpreted as a relative path, so basically, it is put in whatever your current working directory is.

Comment: And often the current working directory is not where you might, as a beginner, expect it to be. There are many questions on SO on this topic resulting from the (perhaps reasonable, but usually unfounded) expectation that the current working directory is the folder where the running script is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will generate one single file in your current working directory.

This because the filename variable contains only the file name. If you want to change the directory you have to specify the full path instead of the name only.

The script is working fine even if i don't know what requirements are, so if you want to know if there are tracebacks, no there aren't.

Anyway it's quite easy.... just try to run it! ;)

Comment: "in the same directory where the python file is stored"—In your **current working directory**, not necessarily the directory containing the Python script.